# I have a question regarding SAF on a Ionic Angular App

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I'm working on the permissions for an app, and I have a question.

Said app was developed initially as an Angular web, and it was very recently wrapped into Ionic in order to make it an App as well.
I wasn't involved on that wrapping process (in fact I have minimal knowledge on Ionic), but right now I have to deal with permissions.

For a bit of context, this app can load .jpgs, .pdfs and .tiff. And when I navigate there and tap on the button that on PC would open the file selector, it does the same on android.

What I'm wondering is, is that file selector some kind of implementation of the Storage Access Framework (SAF)? Because from what I'be seen if it is then I don't need to ask for any specific permissions, since it's the user who chooses to select a file, and who decides what file to select.

I've tried looking online, asking on relevant discord servers, reading documentation, looking for plugins... I'm either bad at looking or everything is quite confusing.

Comment: There are different file and folder selectors under which using saf. But for no one you need any permission. Not for using the picker. Not for using the picked file.